# How can I extract value of variable from script element in Scrapy

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I need to extract some data from a website, I found that all I need is exist in `<script>` element, So I extracted them with this command:

```
script = response.css('[id="server-side-container"] script::text').get()
```

And this is the value of `script`:

```
    window.bottomBlockAreaHtml = '';
    ...
    window.searchQuery = '';
    window.searchResult = {
  "stats": {...},
  "products": {...},
  ...
  };
    window.routedFilter = '';
  ...
    window.searchContent = '';
```

What is the best way to get the value of `"products"` in my python code?

Comment: what is the datatype of ```script``` variable?

Comment: @KazimRaza It's ```str```

Comment: have you tried converting it into a dictionary?

Comment: does the current string looks something like this, 
```
{
"product":{...},
"somethingElse":{...}
}
```

Comment: extracting the text with regular expressions and then using `json.loads()`

Comment: Is there any regex pattern to extract the full value of a variable of a javascript code with python? If there is any I could get the value of ```window.searchResult``` and then convert it to a python dictionary. @Alexander

Comment: you can craft a regex pattern that specific data in the value of the `products` field.  Post the url and I can show you an example

Comment: This is an example URL: ```https://www.loplabbet.se/lopning/```
@Alexander

Answer (score 1):

In your example the best strategy would be to use regex to extract the value of the `window.searchResults` using regex. Then convert it to a dictionary using `json.loads()`, and then getting the value from the  `"products"` key of the dictionary.

For example.

```
import json
import scrapy
import re

class LoplabbetSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "loplabbet"
    start_urls = ["https://www.loplabbet.se/lopning/"]
    pattern = re.compile(r'window\.searchResult = (\{.*?\});', flags=re.DOTALL)

    def parse(self, response):
        for script in response.css("script").getall():
            matches = self.pattern.findall(script)
            if matches:
                results = json.loads(matches[0])
                product = results["products"]
                yield product
```